# Overload function on parent and child - how to access the parent function

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

Here is what I would like to do:

```
class Msg {
    int target;
public:
    Msg(int target): target(target) { }
    virtual ~Msg () { }
    virtual MsgType GetType()=0;
};

inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss,Msg const& in) {
    return ss << "Target " << in.target;
}

class Greeting : public Msg {
    std::string text;
public:
    Greeting(int target,std::string const& text) : Msg(target),text(text);
    MsgType GetType() { return TypeGreeting; }
};

inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss,Greeting const& in) {
    return ss << (Msg)in << " Text " << in.text;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as the cast to Msg on the second last line fails as Msg is abstract. I would however like to have the code to output the information for the parent in only one place. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, just to be clear, it is this line `return ss << (Msg)in << " Text " << in.text;` I don't know how to write.

Comment: it violates const correctness.

Comment: Instead of `(Msg)in`, write `static_cast<const Msg &>(in)`.

Comment: "in.text" ? You are accessing private member using dotted notation ..which would anyways give a compilation error. Accesing private members can only be done by getters and setters functions

Comment: @ArunMu: Or by friends. Or by any member function. The standard doesn't treat getters and setters specially.

Comment: @David..yup ..right. I missed it.

Comment: Thanks. The private thing was an overlook as this was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ss<<(Msg const&)in`.
And probably you have to make operator a friend of `Greeting` class.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

typedef enum {  TypeGreeting} MsgType;

class Msg {
    friend inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss,Msg const& in);

    int target;
public:
    Msg(int target): target(target) { }
    virtual ~Msg () { };
        virtual MsgType GetType()=0;
};

inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss,Msg const& in) {
    return ss << "Target " << in.target;
}

class Greeting : public Msg {
    friend inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss,Greeting const& in);

    std::string text;
public:
    Greeting(int target,std::string const& text) : Msg(target),text(text) {};
    MsgType GetType() { return TypeGreeting; }

};

inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss,Greeting const& in) {
    return ss << (Msg const&)in << " Text " << in.text;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Greeting grt(1,"HELLZ");
    std::cout << grt << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Not great design, but solves your problem.